# Multiple errors while connecting to a database - python3.7

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

whenever I execute the following mysqlclient commands in python(3.7.4), a bunch of errors show up.

```
import MySQLdb
import mysql.connector
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                     port='3306',
                     database='py_test',
                     user='arnav',
                     password='1234')
db_cur = db.cursor()
db_cur.execute('insert into pass values ( \'arnav\', \'0000\' )')
```

These are the errors and I can't seem to find what the problem is. And my server is running just fine.

errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\arnav\Desktop\python programs\sql.py", line 8, in <module>
  password='1234')
File "C:\Users\arnav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\arnav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 166, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I have used mysql.connector in the past multiple times and it works perfectly fine, but I need to use mysqlclient for my project. So, please help.

Comment: integer is required. your second input is not an integer obviously.

Comment: Just change your query to **db_cur.execute("insert into pass values ( 'arnav', 0 )")**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used an f-string and it worked.

Comment: Add some explanation as to why and how?